# Data not being entered into database at all?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a strange issue with a project I am currently working on. All the code runs, without error, but the values aren't entered into the database with an INSERT statement.

The code is as follows:

pipe.php (the file calling the query):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

require_once 'includes/Init.php';

Init::initialise();

$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
$db = new Db($config['db']);

$mail = new Mail($email);

$emailbody = $mail->getPlainBody();
$emailsubject = $mail->getSubject();
$from = $mail->getHeader("From");
$to = $mail->getTo();

if ($id = Util::getId($emailsubject))
{

    $ticket = $db->query_assoc("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id=$id");

    if (in_array($from, $config['staff_emails']))
    {
        //staff reply

        $tickets = $ticket['content'].="<ticketsep>$emailbody";

        $db->query("UPDATE tickets SET content=$tickets WHERE ticket_id=$id");

        mail($ticket['email'], "[$id] A member of staff replied to your ticket: ".$ticket['subject'], $emailbody);
    }
    else
    {
        //client reply

        $tickets = $ticket['content'].="<ticketsep>$emailbody";

        $db->query("UPDATE tickets SET content=$tickets WHERE ticket_id=$id");

        foreach ($config['staff_emails'] as $email)
        {
            mail($email, "[$id] [CLIENT RESPONSE] $emailsubject", $emailbody);
        }
    }

}
else
{
    do
    {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);

        if (!Util::in_array_r($id, $db->query_all('SELECT * FROM tickets')))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES \($id, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $from\)");


    foreach ($config['staff_emails'] as $email)
    {
        mail($email, "[$id] [NEW TICKET] $emailsubject", $emailbody);
    }
}
?>
```

This line doesn't work, no data is inserted: `$db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES \($id, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $from\)");`. I can't test the other insert query, as there's no data already ;)

The Db class looks like this (no comments on code style please, most of it works :P):

```
<?php

class Db
{

    private $link;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param array $dbconfig Array of database configuration:
     *
     * host - database host
     * user - database user
     * password - database user password
     * dbname - database name
     * port - database server port
     */
    public function __construct(array $dbconfig)
    {
        $this->link = mysqli_connect($dbconfig['host'], $dbconfig['user'], $dbconfig['password'], $dbconfig['dbname'], $dbconfig['port']);

        if (!$this->link)
        {
            throw new DatabaseException("Unable to connect to database, please check the settings in the config.php file!");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Query the database
     * @param string $query SQL query to run
     * @return mysqli_result
     */
    public function query($query)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
        $this->checkError();
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first row of a query.
     * @param string $query SQL query
     * @return array Enumeriated array of first row contents.
     */
    public function query_first($query)
    {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_row($this->query($query));
        $this->checkError();
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first row of a query as an associative array
     * @param string $query SQL Query
     * @return array Associative array of row. Column name->column value.
     */
    public function query_assoc($query)
    {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query($query));
        $this->checkError();
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets all results as array.
     * @param unknown $query
     * @param string $resulttype
     * @return array
     */
    public function query_all($query)
    {

        if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) # Compatibility layer with PHP < 5.3
                $res = mysqli_fetch_all($this->query($query));
            else
                for ($res = array(); $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($this->query($query));) $res[] = $tmp;

            return $res;
    }

    public function checkError()
    {
        if ($this->error != '')
        {
            throw new DatabaseException("Database Error(s) Occured: $this->error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get this instance of this object.
     * @return Db
     */
    public static function _getInstance()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case "error":
                $this->error = mysqli_error($this->link);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

All the other lines of code in pipe.php run, as I get the email, however no data is added into the database. Does anyone know why, and if so, how can I make it so that data does get inserted?

Comment: Why are there backslashes in your `INSERT` query?

Comment: @str escaping the brackets for PHP.

Comment: You don't have to do that.

Comment: @str D'oh! I remember... Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quote and the `mysql_real_escape_string` method if you want these quotes to be escaped in the data. Here an example :

```
$emailbody = mysql_real_escape_string($mail->getPlainBody());
$emailsubject = mysql_real_escape_string($mail->getSubject());
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($mail->getHeader("From"));

$db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES ($id, '$emailsubject', '$emailbody', '$from')");
```

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) :

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for
>   use in an SQL statement

Comment: I'm knocking my head against the all now :P How embarrassing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add simple quotes to variables' names : `ticket_id = '$id'`.

Comment: 1. Ticket id is set to int. 2. I'm having issues with the Insert statements.

Comment: Yes, even if `$id` contains an int you need to surround it with simple quotes, otherwise ... the query won't insert the data.

Comment: `$db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES \($id, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $from\)");` would be `$db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES ('$id', '$emailsubject', '$emailbody', '$from')");`